# Construct a continuous functional such that $||T||=||x||$ for each $x$ in $X$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. For each $x$ in $X$ construct a continuous functional $T$ such that $||T||=||x||$. (I believe this should be T(x)=||x||, tell me if this question is correct)
I tried with Hahn-Banach but got stuck. I'm a beginner in this topic. Show me a way to prove this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M=\{ax:a\in \mathbb R\}$. Define $T(ax)=a\|x\|$. This is a continuous linear functional on $M$ such that $Tx=\|x\|$ and Hahn  Banach Theorem completes the proof.

Comment: Replace $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$ if you want to consider normed linear space over $\mathbb C$